# Extending Visual Studio to run via custom exe

Tags: visual-studio

I want to create a custom VS project that builds a DLL, but when hitting F5 will run a custom executable that I wrote (which gets the DLL path as parameter).

Is this possible? What API should I use?

Comment: Why not just get the DLL path from a method in die code itself, instead of using a exe to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's easy.

In the project properties, in the Debug tab, select  the Start Action 'Start external program'. This program must be your executable.